# MDB_INVALID : File is not an LMDB file

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu-14.04, caffe, lmdb

I am having a problem going form lmdb files generated on my mac (64-bit) to the jetson tx1 (32-bit)

After a full day of trouble shooting, I've come to the conclusion that lmdb files that work on my TX1 dont work on my mac, and lmdb files that work on my mac don t work on my TX1. I am creating my lmdb files from my mac, and using an external drive to bring them over to the TX1. Does anyone know how I could convert my lmdb file from the 64-bit format to the 32 bit format??

Everything else works smoothly.. for now ^^

Thanks

J

EDIT : Conclusions to my questions

the jetson tx1 is 32 bit and the makefile for caffe had to be modified , specifically for the lmdb part, for it to compile.  Thus, any lmdb created by a 64bit machine will not work for the 32 bit machine and vice versa.  I have a feeling that making the same changes while making caffe on mac could solve this problem, but haven't tried it out yet.

Comment: is it possible you have different [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) on the machines?

Comment: How can I figure that out?? I am using Mac osX 10.11.4 (El Capitan, 64-bit) vs. Ubuntu 14.04 aarch64 32-bit

Comment: OK I think I may have found a hint... When installing caffe, because it is a 32-bit OS,LMDB_MAP_SIZE was reduced from 1099511627776 to 536970912 (based on code provided by someone from the TX1 community)... This explains a lot.  Is there a way for me to convert my mac lmdb filesto accomodate this?  Or should I re install caffe on my mac using the exact same changes? do you think this would affect my normal caffe operations?

Comment: I have no clue. please edit your question to reflect these findings. good luck.